# Firebase function deploy error in a typescript project with several typescript dependances linked via git+https

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hi there I have an issue deploying my typescript express app to firebase via firebase-tools when that project contains another typescript dependancy. Perhaps something is wrong with the build process when running in google functions. Note the program works as expected locally, it is only a problem with deployment.

Here is a repo for the MVE:

https://github.com/jk89/baseRepo

Which loads two dependancies:

https://github.com/jk89/depRepo1

https://github.com/jk89/depRepo2

I get the following error from firebase-tools 'firebase deploy':

```
jty@carrot:~/April2018/typescript-min-ver/baseRepo$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'pricecalculator-e88d6'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> base-repo@0.1.0 build /home/jty/April2018/typescript-min-ver/baseRepo
> npm run tslint && tsc --declaration


> base-repo@0.1.0 tslint /home/jty/April2018/typescript-min-ver/baseRepo
> tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing . directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged . (12.76 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: . folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 8 function webApi(us-central1)...
⚠  functions[webApi(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function load error: Code in file ./lib/index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'dep-repo-1'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/lib/index.js:7:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)


Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

Having trouble? Try firebase deploy --help
```

Surely this is a common use-case using modularized typescript modules. I don't get why it doesn't work?!

Answer (score 8):

When Firebase tries to install and build your functions, it looks at the field in dep-repo-1/package.json  `"module": "./dist/index.js"` and tries to follow it. Since the file doesn't exist, it throws `Error: Cannot find module 'dep-repo-1'`

The file doesn't exist because in each of the submodules, the `dist` directory isn't published to Github, and Firebase doesn't auto-build your npm packages. (`dist/` is included in the [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/jk89/depRepo1/blob/master/.gitignore))

There are some options on how to build your modules:

1. The best practice would be to create a second "published" repository (or a file storage bucket) with only your artifacts in it (include `dist/` and ignore `lib/`). This is similar to how a module that uses `npm publish` would be setup.
2. Just include the `dist/` directory in your repository. This is less clean (as you are including built files in what should be a source-only repository)
3. Create a script `"install": "tsc"` in each module's package.json.  This will run when you do an npm install. Make sure to add typescript to your dependencies list, since the Firebase build environment doesn't have it pre-installed.

Comment: Ok so yes I can use something like a private npm publish but I want to avoid this as it is a paid solution / adds complexity which seems unnessesary. Solution 2 sucks enough for me to not consider it. Next my code already implements 3 with the "prepare": "npm run build" within each package.json (should be the same as "install":"tsc") of the deps, there is an issue with this within google functions env but not locally. I am looking for a solution to this problem as "prepare" works locally and is standard npm behaviour which should be the same in google cloud